# How to export "Smart Animate" from Figma to React/LottieFiles?

Tags: reactjs, lottie, figma

I have a "[Smart Animate](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039818874-Create-advanced-animations-with-Smart-Animate)" animation on Figma.

**I want to use this smart animate animation in my React app**.
There is a way or a tool to do that?

Is possible to create a LottieFile JSON from Figma smart animate? There is no doc on the web..

Comment: You have to use animation plugins such as Jitter []

Answer (score 0):

As of the moment, this feature is Not yet supported natively by Figma.

You have to use animation plugins such as [Jitter][1], instead of Smart Animate, to create animations in Figma and be able to export them to Lottie format.